# Getting and displaying the source code of a web page in android's textbox or a label

Tags: android, web

I want to be able to get the Source code of a web page (like http://www.google.com) and display it in the Android main activity's text box or a label box... Here is the current code i've written. But it doesn't load the code in the **EditText**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public String html = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    EditText t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    t.setText(html);
}
```

Comment: And yes i have included ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the manifest

Comment: Not exactly... cause that resolves "Getting the source code" but i am trying to display the source code in a textview after getting it... Which isn't working

Comment: First step: Remove the empty catch block to see the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `EditText` should be chained with `TextView`. Make changes in in layout file similar to this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_edittext_control.htm). You will get the content displayed. I hope it helps. Give it a try. If it doesn't work then let me know. I am sure it will work though.

TRY using `t.setText(html, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)`;

Comment: I made the necessary changes in the layout file... It still isn't working

Comment: Do you mind showing layout file?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: `  <TextView

       
 android:id="@+id/textView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

        android:text="@string/example_edittext" />
`

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/enter_text"
        android:inputType="text" />
</RelativeLayout>